# What are some of the most appropriate ways for serving a large scale django app on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: django, google-compute-engine

I am working on a project that will presumably have a lot of user uploaded content and also a fairly large user base. I am now looking for deploying this app to the **Google Compute Engine**.

I have looked up for the possible options and **nginx+gunicorn** seems to be a good option. In the beginning I am going to be using a single ns-1 instance with 100 GB persistent hard drive and **google cloud sql** for serving my database.

But I want to make things scalable so that I can add more instances and disk storage without any hustle in the future. But I am very confused how to do that. So the main concern is.

**I want such setup so that I can extend my disk space and no. of Google Compute Instances whenever I want.**

Comment: Your question is extremely broad - please consider narrowing it down to a specific challenge you want to solve. In any case, you might check out Google Cloud storage as a place to store uploaded content instead of a persistent hard drive. Also google 'load balancing with Google Compute'.

Comment: Google App Engine might also be a better fit for your use case.

Comment: You can look into Compute Engine Autoscaler.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a fully scalable architecture, a good approach is to separate computation / serving, from file storage, and both from data storage. Going part by part:

- file storage - Google Cloud Storage - by storing common service files in a GCS bucket, you get a central repository that is both highly-redundant, and scalable;
- data storage - Google Cloud SQL - gives you a highly reliable, scalable MySQL-like database back-end, which can be resized at will to accommodate increasing database usage;
- front-ends - GCE instance group - template-generated web / computation front-ends, setting up a resource pool into which a forwarding rule (load balancer) distributes incoming connections.

In a nutshell, this is one of the most adaptable set-ups I can think of, while you keep control over every aspect of the service and underlying infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to run a Python app on Google App Engine, which will auto-scale your instances (both up and down) and it supports Django, as mentioned by [@spirulence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/307929/spirulence) in the comments.

Here are some starting points:

- [Django and Cloud SQL support on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django)
- [Running Pure Django Projects on Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel)
- [Third-party Libraries in Python 2.7](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27)

The last link shows which versions of Django are currently supported.